# What shall I do if the PIT in ElasticSearch is expired?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, pagination, paging, point-in-time

I'm trying using the [Point In Time API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html) for pagination implementation and I got the exception message below while using an expired pit id:

```
pplication exception:  ResponseError: search_phase_execution_exception
    Root causes:
        search_context_missing_exception: No search context found for id [129]
```

It always happens if some users open my web page and try scroll the list after a long time, for example, he/she leaves the tablet and comes back after two hours.

My question is what shall I do while the pit id is expired?
If the only thing I can do is that showing an error message on my web page?

Answer (score 2):

you would need to track where the user was with this request and then make a new one from that page, Elasticsearch cannot handle this for you though

Comment: If I make a new PIT for that page in a infinite scrolling pagination, duplicate items may appear in the full list, right?